# Gtk / Gtkmm Kinetic Scrolling

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

I am designing a GUI that requires kinetic scrolling for my application and I am using GTK (coming from Qt) and I have the following code:

```
   Gtk::Window * wnd          = new Gtk::Window();
   Gtk::ScrolledWindow * scr  = new Gtk::ScrolledWindow();
   Gtk::Layout * lay          = new Gtk::Layout();
   Gtk::VBox *   vbox         = new Gtk::VBox();

   wnd->add(*scr);
   scr->add(*vbox);

   for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
   {
      Gtk::Button * btn = new Gtk::Button();
      btn->set_label("Click Me");

      vbox->pack_start(*btn);
      btn->show();
   }

   scr->set_kinetic_scrolling(true);

   wnd->show();
   scr->show();
   lay->show();
   vbox->show();
```

and this is what you get:

[image]

This [link](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1ScrolledWindow.html#a88132d21cc8378c793889b9fa20ac1ca) tells me the following:

> **void Gtk::ScrolledWindow::set_kinetic_scrolling     (   bool** 
>     **kinetic_scrolling = true  )**
>
> Turns kinetic scrolling on or off.
>
> Kinetic scrolling only applies to devices with source
>   **Gdk::SOURCE_TOUCHSCREEN**.
>
> Since gtkmm 3.4:
>
> Parameters
>       kinetic_scrolling true to enable kinetic scrolling.

I tried grabbing the button with the mouse and to kinetically scroll but as expected, it does not work. I don't have a touch screen yet and I need to experiment with my mouse, Is there any way I can do this?

I also found the [following](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/namespaceGdk.html#gaa2b575499ce34e8b79386b2db0c3c95ca19078c10a5b51c03718e7c009e5e9f7a):

```
enum InputSource {
  SOURCE_MOUSE,
  SOURCE_PEN,
  SOURCE_ERASER,
  SOURCE_CURSOR,
  SOURCE_KEYBOARD,
  SOURCE_TOUCHSCREEN,
  SOURCE_TOUCHPAD,
  SOURCE_TRACKPOINT,
  SOURCE_TABLET_PAD
}
    An enumeration describing the type of an input device in general terms.
```

Is there any way I can emulate the type of device? I want to see it working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must have a touch event. Use GtkInspector (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) then in the **Visual** tab, set **Simulate touchscreen** (as shown below):

[image]

It should work. [More on Gtk Inspector](http://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GTK+/Inspector)